# Jquery ui tabs: add custom class to created tabs

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, tabs

I use jquery ui tabs http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#default and i allow the user to create a new tab by pressing a button, i want the new tab to have an html tag like this class="class_name" appended to it, how can i do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your tab-creation code, simply use

```
$('.tabClass').addClass('foo');
```